# Headphone Volume buttons

Tags: nexus-5, volume-control, headphones

I've got a Bose qc15 headset with online volume and call buttons. The call button works with my Nexus 5 but not the volume buttons. Is there a way to get the volume buttons to work?

Comment: Related (and possible duplicate): [Headphone Volume buttons do not work](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/26718)

Comment: Related: [Does android, specifically the HTC Incredible, support headphone volume buttons?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/6276)

Comment: Related: [How to make volume buttons on earphones/headphones work with Android?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/44144)